# git stash - Guardar y ver mensajes personalizados

Tags: git

estoy haciendo un **git stash** en el que guardo un mensaje personalizado:

```
git stash save 'mi mensaje'
```

Estoy intentando leer ese mensaje.

Puedo usar:

```
git stash show
```

y así puedo ver un listado de los ficheros guardados. Si lo uso de la siguiente forma:

```
git stash show -1
```

me aparece un diff de esos ficheros, pero no el mensaje.

¿Cómo puedo ver el mensaje?

Answer (score 1):

Para ver la lista con todos los cambios guardados provisionalmente se usa el comando:

```
git stash list
```

Con el aparecen los mensajes personalizados (si los hay) y el número de cada guardado.
se puede ver sólo el último indicando el numero 1:

```
git stash list -1
```